# Attempt to translate the song "Still Alive"

Tags: classical-latin, translation-check

#### Important note

Given that some looks like that don't understand the importance of macros [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVGGqzJ-g6g) is some reference by ScorpioMartinus where explains that speaking Latin without their macros is like speaking German without their umlauts, or Spanish without their accents.

#### Original text

The English lyrics of the song can be found [here](https://genius.com/Ellen-mclain-still-alive-lyrics). Can I please have feedback on the translation?

```
Hic fuit triumphus
Sum faciens notátio hòc: Magnus triumphus
Est difficilis exaggeráre satisfactionem meam
Aperture Science
Agimus quod débemus
Nam possumus
Pró bonó omnis nostrí
Preater quí sunt mortés

Sed nón est sensus in plóráre pro omnés erroribus
Simpleciter permaneá cónorári ad nón habés tartam
Atque scientia impetrátur actus esse
Atque agis únum bonum gladium
Pró populó quí est adhúc vívens

Ne sum írata quidem
Ego esse valde sincerus hóc tempó
Etsí frangistí cor meum
Necávistíque mé
Frangistíque mé ad partés
Éiectvistíque omnés partés ad únum ignum
Cruentor cum ea partés cremátus sunt, nam eram nimis felix pro té!

Nunc haec puncta datórum facunt pulchra linea
Sumusque é beta
Sumus vulgans in tempó
Ergó sum superbus quod sum cremátus
Cógitá omnis rem quae nós dicedevimus
Pró populó quí est adhúc vívens

Í ante mé et proficíscére mé
Puto quod màlo intus esse
Forsitan inveniés aliquem quem té axiliare
Forsitan Black Mesa
Id fuit únus iocus
Há! há! Procul opportunus
Utcumque, hoc pastelus est maguns
Est valde iucundus et umidus

Ecce mé adhúc loquiens
Dum est scientia ad agendum
Cum video foris, facit mé delectens quod nón sum tú
Habeò experímentum ad facendum
Est investigatio ad facendum
Populís quí sunt adhúc vívens

Et credére mé, ego sum adhúc vívens
Sum scientiam agere et sum adhúc vívens
Sentió vanus et sum adhúc vívens
Dum es moriens, eró adhúc vívens
Et cum mortus tuí, ego eró Adhúc vívens
Adhúc vívens
Adhúc vívens
```

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at briefly, it's extremely literal so you have a lot of Englishisms, but maybe that is ok for what you want to do? Just be aware that when you do word-for-word conversions from English into Latin, sometimes the actual meaning will be different than what the English intends.

For example, *hic fuit triumphus* means "There was a triumph here." because in this sentence *hic* means "here" not "this". If you want to say "This was a triumph", then you would perhaps say something like *Id triumphus fuit*. Just because *hic* can mean "this", doesn't mean it will mean that in any construction you make. Although it could treated substantively when it starts a sentence often hic means "here". For example, from Ovid: *hic fuit, hic cubuit...* "Here she was, here she lay..."

Likewise, one way a Roman could say "I am making a note here" is *Enoto nunc*. The expression *Sum faciens X...* is an English way of speaking that a Roman would not use. For example, imagine if someone said to you "I exist doing a note at this place." That would sound weird to you, wouldn't it? That's what it would sound like to a Roman if you said to them *Sum faciens notátio hòc*.

I guess the important thing is what your purpose is in making the translation? That purpose will dictate the style of writing and level of accuracy required.

Comment: You claim 'hic fuit triumphus means "There was a triumph here." ' is categorically wrong. My latin grammar manual says that hic/haec/hoc are the latin version of esto (they are written in spanish), remarking that hic/haec/hoc remarks the nearnest deictic zone, making the mandatory translation of spanish's esto to latin, and the english this is another one-to-one equivalent translation to my native Sprachen.

Comment: Also I am a very literal being.

Comment: Also 'Estoy tomando una nota aquí' is also a prettry 1-to-1 translation of the english 'I am making a note here'. And I feel like the latinisation of the spanish terms are perfectly fine.

Comment: @Elelphantus The problem is that hic is not just a pronoun, it is also an adverb meaning "here" and in the sentence you constructed a Roman would most likely treat it as the adverb, not the pronoun.

Comment: WRONG. I used hic, not híc, Note the importance of being attend to the macrons.

Comment: @Elelphantus My main problem with *hic* there is the gender, and fixing that would remove the ambiguity (on which point I agree with @TylerDurden). It's natural to want to make it agree with *triumphus* as it is a copular sentence, but it's actually elliptical for "this situation" or "this thing" or similar; *Haec erat triumphus* would look better IMO. As for the rest, the idea that literally translating Spanish will generally yield acceptable Latin is wrong.

Comment: @Cairnarvon As I said, there is no ambiguity because I used hic and not híc. And what as wrong with my translation?

Comment: @Elelphantus Nothing is wrong with it, it is just that there are some transverbalizations. If you are happy with a literal transverbalized then it should do fine.

Comment: @TylerDurden What do you mean with transverbalized?